# Which was the automatic search tool from Google or Bing that used a link?

Tags: google-search, bing

I remember there was a version of Google or Bing that you could input a search query, hit enter, and get the link for that, and send it to someone, and they could watch the query type itself out and search for the query?

If anyone could remind me what that web app was, that would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Google](http://google.com):** [Let Me Google That for You](http://lmgtfy.com/)

**[Bing](http://www.bing.com/):** [Let Me Bing That for You](http://letmebingthatforyou.com)

**[DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/):** [Let Me DDG That for You](http://lmddgtfy.net)

Answer (score 0):

Nice link! For any other website, you can use the [iMacros browser addon](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) for IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
URL GOTO=http://www.google.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:* ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT="your search"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=NAME:btnG&&VALUE:Search
```

"your search" is the keyword you want to search for. The same kind of macro can be recorded and shared for **any** website.

Comment: the problem is, the user you share it with has to have iMacros installed...nice idea though! +1

Comment: yes. But if you embed the macro in a link, the user will be prompted to install iMacros (works at least with Firefox): http://run.imacros.net/?code=VkVSU0lPTiBCVUlMRD03MDAwOTA4IFJFQ09SREVSPUZYClRBQiBUPTEKVVJMIEdPVE89aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLwpUQUcgUE9TPTEgVFlQRT1JTlBVVDpURVhUIEZPUk09TkFNRToqIEFUVFI9TkFNRTpxIENPTlRFTlQ9eW91cjxTUD5zZWFyY2gKVEFHIFBPUz0xIFRZUEU9SU5QVVQ6U1VCTUlUIEZPUk09SUQ6dHNmIEFUVFI9TkFNRTpidG5HJiZWQUxVRTpTZWFyY2g%3D

Comment: details here: http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Social_Scripting